# Data center failure probability

Tags: probability

I have the following problem:

There's a data center with 500 servers. Incoming requests are handled by each server with equal probability. Each server gets 4 requests per second on average, and crashes if it gets more than 10. I need to **approximate** the probability that  no server crashes during a single second.

My solution is to compute the probability of a single server crashing. If X is a random variable counting the number of requests a per second a server gets, then X is distributed Poisson(4), so the probability *p* of a server crashing is

$\sum_{k=0}^{10}\frac{4^ke^-4}{k!}$

I can then think of the data center as 500 independent trials with this probability and approximate it as a normal.

Is this the correct way to solve this?

Comment: Your approach makes sense to me. However I have 2 questions. 1) why is it a Poisson distribution?  2) $(p)^{500}$ is a single number, how do you "approximate" a single number as a normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, if $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are independent Poisson random variables with mean 1, then:

$Y=\sum_{i=1}^λ X_i$
is a Poisson random variable with mean λ.

The only thing you can aproximate to normal (by CLT) is the  probability of a server crashing:

$P(X > 10) = P(Z > \frac{10.5-4}{\sqrt{4}})$ and then the probability of no crashes in 500 servers is

$\left( 1-P(Z > \frac{10.5-4}{\sqrt{4}})\right)^{500}$

the 10.5 is because the correction for continuity